# When to use for loop vs one-liner

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there any difference in performance between a one-liner like the one in the example below, or the for loop? Here's a snippet of code that I was using to do stuff:

```
# convert to integer, subtract 1, and change to 0 if number is < 0
tile_ids =  map(lambda x: max(int(x)-1, 0), child[0].text.split(','))
```

Is it better to do that, or write out this:

```
for tile_id in child[0].text.split(','):
    tile_id = int(tile_id) - 1
    if tile_id < 0:
        tile_id = 0
```

Also, is there a reason to use one over the other?

Comment: Third option, the middle ground: `tile_ids = [max(int(x) - 1, 0) for x in child[0].text.split(',')]`

Comment: List comprehensions are faster. If they can fit on one line, use them over the `for` loop option, otherwise consider readability first and use the loop. `map()` with `lambda` is generally slower (lots of function frames created for all the map calls); use `map()` when you have a native function / method.

Comment: You could find the difference in performance yourself using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module.  As for a reason to prefer one over the other, the readability of the second would be a good enough reason for me.

Comment: Also bear in mind that while `map` returns a list in Python 2 it returns an iterator in Python 3, so if you want a list then you'd need to wrap it in a `list` call so it makes more sense to use a list comp. Also (as Martijn said), doing it with a list  comp (or traditional `for` loop) instead of `map` saves an extra level of function call on every item; Python function calls are relatively slow compared to C function calls.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't need a list, which is why I used map.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I'll go with this. It's readable and doesn't take up 5 lines.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, you don't gain so much in terms of performance using a `map` instead of a for-loop. Probably, using the map is a bit worse than the latter approach, since you are implicitly using "extra-stuff" that, in this case, is not very useful.

The "map-approach" can be very useful when you have the capabilities to parallelize tasks. In that case you can surely achieve better performances than a plain for-loop.

I prefer the second version, thanks to readability. Another way is to use a list-comprehension:

`title_ids = [max(int(x)-1,0) for x in child[0].text.split(',')]`